# Name Method Error, undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting this error message when I try to load my sign up page with devise. I have a name input in my migrate file, so I am not sure where the no method error is coming from.

Error:

NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
Showing /Users/ericpark/rails_projects/bloccit-2/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `name' for #

For page new.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter name" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter email" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter password confirmation" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected

   def configure_permitted_parameters
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
   end
end
```

Migrate File for Users:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :name #Added by Bloc.io


      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run migration `rake db:migrate` after adding the migration file?

Comment: Yes, rake db ran without problems

Comment: What is the output of `User.last` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, that part of your migration is being ignored. So lets build a new migration to add name to the users table.

In console, run:

```
rails g migration addNameToUsers name:string
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create users with names from the rails console? If you can't you probably need to reset your database (rake db:reset).